Why do I get a black screen with Console Sessions and RDP sessions for certain users only
I have a Windows 2019 Server that is a member of my local domain. I am able to use VMWare Web Console to login or use RDP without issue.  Other users, including server administrators and Domain Administrators can log in but only get Black Screens. CTRL+ALT+END will bring up the menu. But no Start Menu and no desktop, just blackness.
Here is where it get's interesting. From the same computer I can login with 1 username that works and 1 that causes black screen, so it's not a driver issue, connection issue or anything related to the originating computer. There are GPO's that regulate who can use RDP, but both users are allowed login through Terminal Services and in fact the other user is logged in they just have a black screen.  In fact there are no differences in either the Domain Level GPO's and the local GPO's, there is nothing in the local security Policy either. I have rebooted the machine, applied the latest updates etc.
This is clearly a credentials/permissions issue, but I've exhausted every possibility I can think of. Anyone have any ideas?

The problem is that explorer is not started. Sometimes it can take a long time before it starts, especially if the server is busy. You can try to start a new task from task manager, explorer.exe and see if they now get the desktop. If so, you can try to narrow it down. Also, make sure you reboot the server.

You're right explorer is not started, in fact if I log in to the same server with the credentials that work and look at the services running for the other user (black screen user), it only has 4 services running.  Client Server Runtime Process, Desktop Window Manager, Usermode Font Driver Host and Windows Logon Application.  But I can leave it on the Black screen for 20 minutes and it never finishes loading. I can close the RDP session and login from the same computer using the other credentials and it loads up just as it should. I can go back and forth this way repeatedly

Closing the RDP session will not log out the user. You can start Task Manager from an admin, and log out all users with a problem and let them login again, see if that fixes it.
